# Check array for values javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following in my angular controller

```
MyUserService.getUserRoles().then(function (data) {
    var userInValidRole = false;
    var role1 = "Role1";
    var role2 = "Role2";

    if ((data.indexOf(role1) > -1) || data.indexOf(role2 ) > -1) {
        userInValidRole = true;
    }
```

This is working as expected.  However I was hoping to do something like:

```
var validRoles = ["Role1", "Role"];
```

and then check

```
    if ((data.indexOf(validRoles) > -1)) {
        userInValidRole = true;
    }
```

However it is not working as expected - is there something I have done wrong?

Comment: `var validRoles = ["Role1", "Role"];` last element typo: Role**2**

Comment: _data_ is already an array and `validRoles` is _another_ array. That's not how `indexOf` works.

Comment: Just use `userInValidRole = data.indexOf(role1) > -1 || data.indexOf(role2) > -1;`

Comment: `data` could have multiple roles, right? So if the user has role1 and role3, you're searching the list ['Role1', 'Role3'] to see if any of the elements are equal to the entire list ['Role1', 'Role'].

Comment: You need to check `validRoles.indexOf()` for *each* value in `data`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if any role in `data` is a `validRole`. And, as @adam-beck suggested below, you cen get rid of the `if` statement:

```
var validRoles = ['Role1', 'Role2'],
    userInValidRole = data.some(function(r){ return validRoles.indexOf(r) > -1; });
```

The advantage of that method is performance. As soon as it finds a correct value, it stops the loop (unlike `.forEach()`, `.map()`, `.filter()`...)

Comment: If userInValidRole should be false otherwise, you could simplfify this: `userInValidRole = data.some(function(r) { return validRoles.indexOf(r) > -1; });

Answer (score 0):

Check array intersection mentioned in this post [Simplest code for array intersection in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript)

```
if(data.filter(function(n) {
    return validRoles.indexOf(n) != -1;
}).length > 0){
userInValidRole = true;
}
```

note: if you want the user to have both roles then check for length == validRoles.length

Comment: This works and I did it for quite some time before learning of `Array.prototype.some`

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about `Array.prototype.some`, good to know!